# Starting threads within Python extensions

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, swig

I'm trying to start a thread from within my SWIG Python C++ extension, however, when I go to run it it produces the following:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm guessing there shouldn't be any issue with the GIL since no python-allocated objects are being used. Or am I wrong in that assumption?

A minimal example:

```
// _MyExtension.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
void threadFunc() {
    std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "Thread ended" << std::endl;
}
void start() {
    std::thread first (threadFunc);
}


// _MyExtension.i
%module _MyExtension
%{
extern void start();
%}
extern void start();


// test.py
import _PyMapper
_PyMapper.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix, the thread has to be detached after being created, like so:

```
void start() {
    std::thread first (threadFunc);
    first.detach();
}
```

Then, it works fine! However, the thread will be killed prematurely once all statements have been completed in the original Python script. This is fixed by adding a function call to your extension that rejoins the thread.